# Laravel Filesystem Overwritting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a function which creates a LogFile Object (my own Model) and writes it to a text file.  For this, I am using Laravels Filesystem.  I first set up my disk in filesystems.php

```
'logFile' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => storage_path('logFile'),
],
```

I then created the function that uses this storage

```
public function setlogFile(Request $request)
{
    $logFile = new LogFile();
    $logFile->created_at = new \DateTime();;
    $logFile->ipAddress = filter_var($request->ip(), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);

    try {
        if(Storage::disk('logFile')->has('logFile.txt')) {
            $size = Storage::disk('logFile')->size('logFile.txt');
            if($size > 2000000) {
                Storage::disk('logFile')->move('logFile.txt', 'archive/' . time() . uniqid() . '-logFile.txt');
            }
        } else {
            Storage::disk('logFile')->put('logFile.txt', $logFile);
        }

        if (Storage::disk('logFile')->append('logFile.txt', $logFile)) {
            return response()->json("Success", 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'something_went_wrong'], 500);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }
}
```

Whats supposed to happen is this.

I firstly obtain a timestamp and the IP of the request, and then create my Object.

I then check to make sure there is a file called logFile.txt in my storage location.  I then get the size of this file.  If it is more than 2MB, I move it to a new location and create a new file.  If it is less than 2 MB, I append my object to it.

Now everything seems to work fine.  The file has a new row of data appended to it on every request.  My problem seems to be that atleast once a day, the file seems to start from scratch.  I dont know if it is because it has hit 2MB, but nothing seems to be saved in the archive folder.

I was just wondering if there is anything wrong with this code that might be causing this issue? I am a bit confused as to why this happens as it should be moving the file?

Thanks

Comment: Not your answer, but: Why are you re-writing a Log functionality? Laravel implements a Log facade that extends the [monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog), with provides many ways to interacting with log files...

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/log-rotate

Comment: Didnt think about using the Log Facade, will switch over to it.  Just to clear something up, the log-rotote which is set in app.php wont have a impact on what I am doing above will it?  This only applies to monolog logging?  Just want to make sure it is not this that is overridding my file.